# BASH: "while read line ???"

Tags: bash

I understand the format below...

```
while read line
do
    etc...
```

However, I saw this yesterday and haven't been able to figure out what `var` would be in the following:

```
while read pkg var
do
    etc...
```

Thanks

Comment: If you do not understand the second code snippet, then you also do not understand the first!

Comment: `help read` might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read` builtin will read multiple whitespace-separated (or, really, separated by whatever is in `$IFS`) values.

```
 echo a b c | (read x y z; echo "$y")   
 #=> b
```

If there are more fields than variables passed to `read`, the last variable gets the rest of the line.

Comment: I missed the IFS value set earlier in the script. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

while loop will read the var one by one , but assign the last parts to one var.

For example, I have a file like:

```
a b c d
```

when run the command

```
$ while read x y
do
   echo $x
   echo $y
done < file
```

Resule:

```
a
b c d
```

You will get "b c d" to $y.

Of course, if you only assign one var (line), then $line will get the whole line.